# Wordpress function does not output all list items

Tags: wordpress

I have this function connected to a short code that is supposed to return all stored social profiles. For now it only outputs the first social profile, even though it got two more. ***I think there is something wrong with the way this code returns the output***, I just don't know how to solve it.

```
function ichi_social_profiles() {

  if( $social_profiles = Youxi()->option->get( 'social_profiles' ) ):

    ?><div class="site-social-profiles">

      <ul class="plain-list"><?php

        foreach( $social_profiles as $profile ):

          $profile = wp_parse_args( $profile, array(
            'title'   => '', 
            'url'     => '#', 
            'icon'    => 'socicon socicon-500px', 
            'new_tab' => 0
          ) );

          $output = '<li>';

            $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $profile['url'] ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $profile['title'] ) . '"' . ( wp_validate_boolean( $profile['new_tab'] ) ? ' target="_blank"' : '' ) . '>';

              $output .= '<span class="' . esc_attr( $profile['icon'] ) . '"></span>';

            $output .= '</a>';

          $output .= '</li>';


          return $output;

        endforeach;

      ?></ul>

    </div><?php endif;

}
add_shortcode('some-ikon', 'ichi_social_profiles');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement is too early, inside of the `foreach` loop, and it is only returning the contents of $output. Also, the `div` tag, the `ul` tag and rest of the HTML are being echoed on the page, instead of being returned by the function.

I would set `$output = ''` at the beginning of the function before the `if` statement, and append HTML to it as you go, then just return $output at the end, after the `endif`.

The WordPress Codex has some examples that may also help, though some are much more complex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I added `ob_start()` to the beginning of the function before any echo call.

at the end of the function I added:

```
$response = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $response;
```